# How do I solve : Input must be a character vector of any length or a list of character vectors, each of which has a length of 1

Tags: r, text-mining, sentiment-analysis

[image]I am trying to analyze customer reviews. My data base is composed of one column named ReqSummary and when I am trying to start my sentiment analysis I receive the following error message: Error in check_input(x) : Input must be a character vector of any length or a list of character vectors, each of which has a length of 1. Here is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)
library(readr)

data.tb <- as_tibble(data.frame(data))
data.tok <- unnest_tokens(data.tb, output="word", input="ReqSummary", to_lower=TRUE, strip_punct=TRUE, strip_numeric=TRUE)
```

Comment: please post your sample `data` a few rows at least

Comment: Hello Anil, I posted a picture of the the sample

Comment: Hi narin.  Not as an image, but please paste it as code which is in [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) format.   Please see tag info more details

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to call the variable by name using the `$` operator:

```
data.tok <- unnest_tokens(data.tb$ReqSummary, output="word", input="ReqSummary", to_lower=TRUE, strip_punct=TRUE, strip_numeric=TRUE)
```